# Count over nested HashMaps with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I am dealing with the following structure.

```
Map<String, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>> ...
```

I would like to increment a counter with the values in the inner HashMap.
I could easily do that with an iterative function or with nested loop. 
However, I am looking for an elegant solution using lambdas.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get the sum of the values of the innermost `Map<Integer,Integer>`s?

Comment: Exactly, that's my goal

Comment: As it stays now your question is unclear. "increment a counter" may be interpreted as `counter=counter+1;` but we still don't know what you consider as `counter`. Use [edit] option and clarify your question (preferably with an example of input and expected result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.values().stream()` in order to get a `Stream` of the values in a `Map`. Then you can repeatedly apply `.flatMap` in order to peel away the nested structures until you get a `Stream<Integer>`. Then you can create an `IntStream` using `.mapToInt` to get the `.sum()` of all the values.

```
int sum = outerMostMap.values().stream()   // HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>
    .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream()) // HashMap<Integer, Integer>
    .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream()) // Integer
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)           // int
    .sum();
```

Comment: Or `.map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream)` instead of `flatMap(map -> ...)` if no lambdas are desired.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution! The output is correct. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @GiovanniGrano `flatMap` combines all the `Stream`s returned by applying the given function onto each element into one `Stream`. It takes all values from the current elements and combines them into a single `Stream` by just concatenating all those `Stream`s. You repeat that until the values are `Integer` and then sum them up.